# C# SQLConnection.Open() hangs, with no exception

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin.forms, sqlconnection

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2019, with Xamarin.Forms, and SQl in SSMS 2018 and have the below code (where [] is used to replace unneccessary information)

```
try
{
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
  {
     connection.ConnectionString = "Server=[ServerName]; Database=[DatabaseName]; User Id= [UserID]; Password=[Password]";

     connection.Open();

     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from [TableName]", connection);

     [Does stuff here]
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex)
}
```

When I run this, it hangs indefinitely at `connection.Open()`. Debug mode continues to run and appears to move on from `Connection.Open()`, but never reaches the next line.

I have attempted this with different versions of the ConnectionString, using different databases and with `Trusted_Connection=true` instead of specifiying the username and password but they have made no difference. Adding `Connection Timeout = 5` to the connectionString has no effect.

I believe it is probably an issue with my settings in SQL but as I am a novice with this I have no idea where to start and the similar forums posts I have checked have been given answers along the lines of `Connection Timeout` ([Connection.open for hangs indefinitely, no exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448857/connection-open-for-hangs-indefinitely-no-exception-is-thrown)) or never got answered.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the database server on the same machine?  If not, is it on the same network?  Can you ping the db server?

Comment: Does the SQL Server have the inbound and outbound blocked on the designated port?

Comment: The server is on the same machine

Comment: SqlConnection.Open works. Connection strings work, although we don't know what *your* connection string is since you've removed every value. There's no infinite block issue, which is why questions that ask about this never get an answer. It's always a timeout issue or a server that isn't working, or a networking issue.

Comment: If you use a local server use `.` or `(local)` or `localhost`, depending on what network protocols are enabled. By default, only shared-memory is enabled. instead of anything else. If you try to connect to a named instance, eg SQL Server Express, include the instance name, eg `.\SQLExpress`. For [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string) ensure SQL Server Express is installed and use `(LocalDB)\MSQLLocalDb`

Comment: If this was a timeout issue, then it wouldn't hang and would instead return an exception, especially when I set the timeout to 2 seconds, right? I am able to connect to the server directly using SSMS and there is no network between the C# and the database as they are on the same device

Comment: using (localDB)\\MSQLLocalDb has resulted in an exception but using .\\SQLExpress had the same issue as before.

The excception returned has the message LocalDb is not supported on this platform

Comment: using localhost returns the SQLException ```"Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)\nSnix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)"```. This appears to be related to Xamarin but I have no idea how it would be causing the problem

Comment: @Mythos By default the inbound and outbound communication for SQL is blocked by Windows Firewall, you should open up port 1433 (I'd double check that port number).

Comment: I have just opened port 1433 with no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you log into SSMS with the credentials that are in the connection string?

Otherwise I've had luck making sure the connection isn't already open or broken first:

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200867/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-c-sqlconnection-open-hangs-with-no-exception).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try code changing line as per below -

connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=[ServerName]; Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName]; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Answer (score -1):

A workaround to this problem is to pass in a cancellation token instance as shown below,

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Toy>> ShowToybox(CancellationToken t)
{
   // notice I turned this into an async operation. 
   // Reason is to let this operation to find its way out if something happens
    var connString = "Server=xyz; Connection Timeout=250";
    //Timeout might not happen, if that is not the case see below..
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        if ( t.IsCancellationRequested) {
            t.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
       // await query here. To fetch records from the toybox table
       return matches;
     }
```

Main issue is that you cannot trust connection.State

To get this working, code that consumes this method should expect something might go wrong.

```
class Program
{
   static void Main()
  {
      var box = new ToxBox(); //it has method shown above
      var s = new CancellationTokenSource();
      s.CancelAfter(400); //it prevents method from hanging
      var task = Task.Run(() = box.ShowToybox(s.Token));
      try
      {
          task.Wait(s.Token);
          var myToys = task.Result();
          Console.WriteLine($"I have {myToys.Count()} toys");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Something happened!"); 
      }
      finally
      {
          s.Dispose(); //this is important
      }  
  }
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: That if statement is redundant as the "ThrowIfCancellationRequested" method makes that evaluation internally. Also, single character parameter/variable names (especially those with no apparent correlation with the purpose) should be avoided at all costs.